# parse deploy : no such file or directory

Tags: parse-platform, terminal, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am implementing Stripe Payment in iOS App and following the steps mentioned here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseStore

On step 7. run "parse deploy" it is showing Deploy Error: no such file or directory

My global.json file:

```
{
  "global": {
    "parseVersion": "1.2.1"
  },
  "applications": {
    "ParseStore": {
      "applicationId": "fZXCNaUOMWiCo7------key---------------------"
        },
    "_default": {
      "link": "ParseStore"
    }
  }
}
```

Terminal Commands and Output:

```
MAC-D05:CloudTest myusername$ parse add
We've changed the way the CLI works.
To save time logging in, you should create an account key.

Type "parse configure accountkey" to create a new account key.
Read more at: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#command-line-account-keys
Email: myemail@gmail.com
Password (will be hidden): 
1:  ParseStore
2:  otherapp1
3:  otherapp2
4:  otherapp3
5:  lsjdfsljdf
Select an App to add to config: 1
Written config for "ParseStore"
MAC-D05:CloudTest myusername$ parse deploy
We've changed the way the CLI works.
To save time logging in, you should create an account key.

Type "parse configure accountkey" to create a new account key.
Read more at: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#command-line-account-keys
Email: myemail@gmail.com
Password (will be hidden): 
Uploading source files
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/Users/myusername/Documents/StripeParse/ParseStore/CloudTest/cloud/main.js
Deploy failed with error:
lstat /Users/myusername/Documents/StripeParse/ParseStore/CloudTest    /public: no such file or directory
Will retry in 0 seconds.

Uploading source files
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/Users/myusername/Documents/StripeParse/ParseStore/CloudTest/cloud/main.js
Sorry, deploy failed again with same error.
Will retry in 1 seconds.

Uploading source files
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/Users/myusername/Documents/StripeParse/ParseStore/CloudTest/cloud/main.js
lstat /Users/myusername/Documents/StripeParse/ParseStore/CloudTest/public: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an empty folder with name 'public' under 'CloudTest' folder and try to deploy....It will work..